# Replace parameter in URL - two parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script for replace prameter:

```
function replaceQueryParam(param, newval, search) {
//condition over accumulation & in url if I use null
if(newval == null){
    ampersand = "";
} else{
    ampersand = "&";
}

var regex = new RegExp("([?;&])" + param + "[^&;]*[;&]?");
var query = search.replace(regex, "$1").replace(/&$/, '');

return (query.length > 2 ? query + ampersand : "?") + (newval ? param + "=" + newval : '');
```

}

And I use it:

```
var str = window.location.search
str = replaceQueryParam('myParam', 'myValue', str)
window.location = window.location.pathname + str
```

It run perfect, but I want use the function edit to parameters with only one redirect. If I have it in onClick event, I cant use:

```
var str = window.location.search
str = replaceQueryParam('myParam', 'myValue', str)
window.location = window.location.pathname + str

var str = window.location.search
str = replaceQueryParam('SecondParam', 'null', str)
window.location = window.location.pathname + str
```

The second parameter I want null (I want delete second parameter from url) - if it by simple.

Thanks and sorry for my English

PS: It can by in jquery

All of my event:

```
$("#typ span").click(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;  
        //if it exist
    if (url.indexOf('typ') > -1){
         var str = window.location.search
         str = replaceQueryParam('typ', $(this).attr('id'), str)
         window.location = window.location.pathname + str

        //if its doesnt exist - add new
    } else {
        if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
           url += '&typ='+$(this).attr('id');
        }else{
           url += '?typ='+$(this).attr('id');
        }
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

if click on span I want do this (add or replace "typ") and null other parameter (if it exist) - with only one redirect.

Comment: Have you tried to replace param first and then set location at last something like: `str = replaceQueryParam('myParam', 'myValue', str); str = replaceQueryParam('SecondParam', 'null', str); indow.location = window.location.pathname + str;`

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt works. The all of event:

[code]$("#typ span").click(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;  
   //if it exist
  if (url.indexOf('typ') > -1){
    var str = window.location.search
    str = replaceQueryParam('typ', $(this).attr('id'), str)
    window.location = window.location.pathname + str
 
   //if its doesnt exist - add new
  } else {
   if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
      url += '&typ='+$(this).attr('id');
   }else{
      url += '?typ='+$(this).attr('id');
   }
   window.location.href = url;
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the existing [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

Example:

```
const url = new URL('http://test.com/products?category=bears&page=3');
url.searchParams.set('category', 'puppies');
console.log(url.href); // Result: http://test.com/products?category=puppies&page=3
```